# BlueStack Android Emulator is not able to connect to internet

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-build, bluestacks

i made a small jquery mobile application that fetches some data from remote server like
http://ip.jsontest.com/
i build it using phonegap online and installed it in BlueStack android emulator for testing,
but i am not able to connect to the server
"web page is not available"
BlueStack is not able to connect to internet, i am not able to search apps even!!!!

my questions are:

1) BlueStack has network settings, if any where can i found them.?

2) Need any special permissions to aapp to Run your JQuery.AJAX method and or access the internet?

Thanks